# How can I connect to the Internet using an ADSL modem?

Tags: networking

I have a dualboot Ubuntu and Windows XP on my PC.

Does Ubuntu require drivers for the onboard Ethernet card? If not, how can I make an Internet conection using an ADSL modem?

Comment: What modem do you have? USB? Who is the manufacturer?

Comment: In the network connections tool there is a section for DSL connections. That might help you.

Answer (score 5):

For network connections we have [Network Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/maverick/net/network-manager) installed as the default tool to connect to networks, and to setup connections. There is also a section to setup a DSL/ADSL connection. Additional drivers for your LAN card are most likely not needed.

To open network manager setting right click on the panel symbol and choose *Edit Connections*:

[image]

In the window that opens choose the DSL Tab and *Add* a new connection:

[image]

Enter the data your ISP needs to connect in the following window:

[image]

If you haven't installed Ubuntu yet best advice is you try out Ubuntu booting from a live CD. There you will have acess to all standard applications including network manager. Just type in your DSL credentials there and enjoy to see your PC connecting.

Answer (score 1):

I think the command line tool to turn on the DSL connection is called "pon" and to disconnect you type "poff" . The command is

```
sudo pon dsl-provider
```

(but I think you can define arbitrary dsl connection names ("dsl-provider" is just a generic default).

Before that you have to call "pppoeconf" to set up the provider metadata (username, password, host to connect to etc). "pppoeconf" means point-to-point-protocol-over-ethernet configuration, I think.

Haven't done this in a long time. Google-search for "ubuntu" "pon" "dsl".

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend installing some router. I understand this may not suit you. But this will protect you from a lot of incoming connections that could harm you. Of course, you are in much better shape with Ubuntu/Linux than under Windows. But even then, make sure you are VERY well protected if you connect your Ubuntu Computer directly on an internet connection.

Ubuntu now offers easy installation of an ADSL-based connection from the Connection Manager. It will ask you for the basic questions, and here you go.

Have a nice day :-)