# How do I auto-connect to a DSL-USB-modem?

Tags: networking, modem

I have Modem called `TP-LINK TD-8817` USB

The problem Who when I log to ubuntu the modem don't run but if I want to run it I should remove the wire of the modem and enter it again

I have to do this every-time I want to run the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Your [TD-8817](http://www.tp-link.com/products/productDetails.asp?class=&content=fea&pmodel=TD-8817) modem can also be connected with the Ethernet network adapter of your PC. See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31327/how-can-i-connect-to-the-internet-using-an-adsl-modem/31341#31341) on DSL connections. It is best advice to do so as connecting by USB can only be done with (usually proprietary) drivers and network needs to be bridged to the USB driver. The problem you encounter may likely come from the USB driver that only allows you to connect after re-plugging your device.

For your modem use this socket to connect with an [Ethernet cat5 patch cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) to the LAN port on your computer:

[image]

Once your modem is connected with the Ethernet port all traffic can be handled by default Ubuntu applications withouth the need to install any additional drivers. You will be able to autoconnect to the modem in network manager settings:

[image: Network Manager Menu]

Edit your eth0 settings by ticking Connect automatically in order to connect everytime you turn on your PC:

[image]

In case you need to stick to USB connection then the option to autoconnect may depend your USB driver's capabilities.

Comment: I did That but it declines to run automatically when I log to my PC . Is there any other solution even commands in Terminal .

Comment: sorry to hear that. Are other network connections installed? Is you modem powered on before you login?

Comment: there is other connection but for LAN and Idon't use it
The modem run when I turn on the PC but when I log to ubuntu it doesn't run.

Comment: Is there any other answer?

Comment: was not the title clear ?